# How to pass the login information in Android Studio

Tags: php, android

I have a list view on android studio that contains a panel of players. However, I want the list view to be unique to each user so that they can only see the players that they have added to the database and nobody else. However when I pass the variable '$userid' it returns nothing to the list view. I have tried to pass the user_id as a session variable from the login.php file to the panel.php file but this has not solved the problem.

This is the php from the login page where I create the user_id which is a foreign key in the 'panel' table on mysql

```
    <?php
session_start();

require "conn.php";
//$theUserID = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['user_id']);
$user_name= mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST["user_name"]);
$user_pass= mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST["password"]);

$mysqli_qry="SELECT user_id FROM employee_data WHERE username LIKE '$user_name'
 AND password LIKE '$user_pass';";

$result=mysqli_query($conn,$mysqli_qry);



if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0){
while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
  $_SESSION['user_id']=$row['user_id'];
    //$userid=$row['user_id'];

  }
//  while ($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
  //$_SESSION['user_id']=$row['user_id'];

echo "Login successful";
}
 else {
  echo "login unsuccessful".mysqli_error($conn);
}


?>
```

This is the php code from the panel page:

```
<?php
session_start();

if(!isset($_SESSION['user_id'])){
    header('Location: login.php');
}

include 'conn.php';
$userid=$_SESSION['user_id'];

$people= array();

$sql= "SELECT name FROM panel where user_id='$userid'";


$stmt= $conn->prepare($sql);

$stmt->execute();

$stmt->bind_result($name);

while ($stmt->fetch()) {
  $temp= [
    'name'=>$name

  ];
  array_push($people,$temp);
}
echo json_encode($people);
?>
```

The query in the panel.php file works with no issues and posts to the list view if i manually insert the user_id for example

```
$sql= "SELECT name FROM panel WHERE user_id='1'";
```

Comment: you forgot to tell what is the problem

Comment: I don't understand your question? if you have a list of  added players you need a reference to the user that added them, why not have a userId field that maps to the user who added the player?

Comment: Well, for a start, your PHP code for the login page looks like it's wide open to SQL injections...

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko the query returns nothing to screen, unless I hardcode the where clause

Comment: @MichaelDodd thanks for your input! anything to solve the issue

Comment: Please print your $_GET array and check

Comment: the problem is apparently not with mysqli/database but with sending whatever variable from one script to another. looks like you need a session

Comment: Most likely you are not getting $_GET['user_id'] value. You need to save the user_id in session.

Comment: Oh we think the same @YourCommonSense

Comment: @YourCommonSense hi thanks for your help. I have tried to create a session variable for the user_id but with no luck

Comment: to just create a variable is not enough. you should pass it somehow from request to request

Comment: @YourCommonSense I have created a session variable for the user_id and passed this through to the panel.php class. Still nothing is being passed across.

Comment: sorry I have no knowledge for Android at all. there are many questions on how to get the user id, you may want to browse some of them